# Documentation on how non boolean datatypes are interpreted for if-statement

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement

I am too paranoid to use other datatype than `bool` for if-statement. For example, I already know that non-empty `list` is interpreted as true, no matter what is inside.

```
123 if [True] else 456
# 123

123 if [False] else 456
# 123

123 if [] else 456
# 456
```

However, I just noticed that `numpy.ndarray` acts differently:

```
123 if np.array([True]) else 456
# 123

123 if np.array([False]) else 456
# 456

123 if np.array([]) else 456
# 456
```

My lack of true understanding is preventing me from using these concise syntax confidently.
**Can I someone point me to/give a definitive documentation on this?
Maybe Python actually checks for an implementation of some '__xxx__' function on the object?**

Comment: Single element arrays have the truthy value of that element.  But multi-element arrays raise an 'ambiguity' error when the context expects a single boolean value.  In general do not use arrays in an 'if'.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to \_\_bool\_\_, now I got the mechanism which is clearly explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__

Comment: Also https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans

Comment: `np.array([]).__bool__()` gives a DeprecationWarning:g in recent versions.  `np.array([1,3]).__bool__()` gives the Ambiguity error.